# How to represent algebraic data type in relational database via ORM?

Tags: python, database-design, orm, django-models, algebraic-data-types

below is the grammar I use to parse string and store the result into Python data structures.

```
;; subject_code is a string which matches certain pattern.

code => <subject_code>

prereq => one_of | normal | and | either_or

one_of => “one of” code*

normal => code*

and => prereq “and/plus” prereq

either_or => “either” prereq “or” prereq
```

The code is [here](https://gist.github.com/luckykevin/8660244).

How can I store prereq in to relation database via django ORM?

I've went through the docs of django but I haven't got a clue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't use django, but I guess you need something to store trees in a relational DB. In this case, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/9677681/989121

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django tree modeling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677681/django-tree-modeling)